# E: Unable to locate package mkinitrd

Tags: install-from-source

```
root@cliu-HP-ZBook-15:/# apt-get install mkinitrd   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done   
E: Unable to locate package mkinitrd
```

Can somebody tell how to install mkinitrd?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install every piece of software that way - Ubuntu only has a limited list in it's memory. Also, `mkinitrd` doesn't exist on Ubuntu.

A bit of research would have shown you that:

> "In ubuntu `mkinitramfs` command is used instead of `mkinitrd`"

[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mkinitrd-832727/#post4100263), from [this google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mkinitrd%20install).